# Записать в переменную JS все дочерние блоки кроме указанного

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени! Вопрос такой - есть у меня div блок и в нем некоторое количество дочерних div блоков с классом getmore и мне надо получить в переменную весь html дочерних блоков но при этом изъять из него указанный дочерний блок например последний с id refer

```
 <div id='zzz'>
    <div class="getmore"></div>
    <div class="getmore"></div>
    <div class="getmore"></div>
    <div class="getmore" id="refer"></div>
 </div>
```

пробовал так я записываю в переменную js дочерние элементы так

```
var zzz = $("#zzz").html();
```

потом при помощи str replace просто удалять div с нужным id но работает не корректно, как можно по другому более нормально получить только нужные мне блоки исключив к примеру последний?

Comment: `$('#zzz .getmore:not(#refer)')`

Comment: @Grundy опередил :)

Comment: @Grundy, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Grundy да можно пожалуйста в ответ что бы я мог пометить, и пожлуйста как это в переменную записать, а то я сейчас попробовал по своемуи что то не так получилось(

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопросы в вопросы :-)

Comment: @dantelol, добавил ответ. Ты уверен, что тебе нужен именно html (строка), а не сами элементы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться селектором [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), в котором указать элементы, которые не должны входить в выборку.

Например так:

```
var elements = $('#zzz .getmore:not(#refer)');
```

Если нужны элементы, на этом можно остановиться.

Если нужен html из этих элементов, можно использовав [метод `map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) получить html для каждого элемента, получить из коллекции обычный массив с помощью [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) и объединить его с помощью функции [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var htmlString = elements.map((i,el)=>el.outerHTML).get().join('');
```

```js
var elementsWithoutRefer = $('#zzz .getmore:not(#refer)');
elementsWithoutRefer.css('color', 'red');

console.log(elementsWithoutRefer.map((i, el) => el.outerHTML).get().join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='zzz'>
  <div class="getmore">1</div>
  <div class="getmore">2</div>
  <div class="getmore">3</div>
  <div class="getmore" id="refer">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно получить не только содержимое а и сами кнтейнеры? вот так что бы было <div class="getmore">1</div>
  <div class="getmore">2</div>
  <div class="getmore">3</div>

Comment: @dantelol, так сейчас именно это и выводится, смотри вывод в консоли